# R in counting data

Tags: r, histogram, outliers, bell-curve

Right now I'm trying to do a bell curve on a file called output9.csv on my.

Here is my code, I want to uses z score to detect outliers, and uses the difference between the value and mean of the data set.The difference is compared with standard deviation to find the outliers. va

```
#DATA LOAD
data <- read.csv('output9.csv')
height <- data$Height

hist(height) #histogram

#POPULATION PARAMETER CALCULATIONS
pop_sd <- sd(height)*sqrt((length(height)-1)/(length(height)))
pop_mean <- mean(height)
```

But I have this error after I tried the histogram part,

```
> hist(height)
Error in hist.default(height) : 'x' must be numeric
```

how should I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have your data I can only guess. Can you provide it? Or at least a portion of it?

What class is your data? You can use `class(data)` to find out. The most common way is to have table-like data in `data.frames`. To subset one of your columns to use it for the `hist` you can use the `$` operator. Be sure you subset on a column that actually exists. You can use `names(data)` (if `data` is a `data.frame`) to find out what columns exist in your data. Use `nrow(data)` to find out how many rows there are in your data.

After extracting your `height` you can go further. First check that your `height` object is `numeric` and has something in it. You can use `class(height)` to find out.

As you posted in your comment you have the following names

```
names(data) 
# [1] "Host" "TimeStamp" "TimeZone" "Command" "RequestLink" "HTTP" [7] "ReplyCode" "Bytes"
```

Therefore you can extract your `height` with

```
height <- data$Bytes
```

Did you try to convert it to numeric? `as.numeric(height)` might do the trick. `as.numeric()` can coerce all things that are stored as characters but might also be numbers automatically. Try `as.numeric("3")` as an example.

Here an example I made up.

```
height <- c(1,1,2,3,1)
class(height)
# [1] "numeric"

hist(height)
```

This works just fine, because the data is numeric.

In the following the data are numbers but formatted as characters.

```
height_char <- c("1","1","2","3","1")
class(height_char)
# [1] "character"

hist(height_char)
# Error in hist.default(height) : 'x' must be numeric
```

So you have to coerce it first:

```
hist(as.numeric(height_char))
```

..and then it works fine.

For future questions: Try to give [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hey thank you! this is the erorr I have after class(height): class(height)
[1] "NULL"

Comment: So obviously there is nothing stored in your object `height`. Are you sure there is something in your data? Are you sure about the subset you do?

Comment: is there a way to create a height?

Comment: @sumbolrush so sir can I ask so is csv file not being read correctly or should I pick a column to set as my height? I want to use the byte column as height.

Comment: @sumbolrush hey sir are you there, sorry I'm really lsot right now. after class(d), what do I do now? how do I extract the height? Since i want use the Bytes column

Comment: What are the names of your columns? Try `names(data)`.

Comment: hey sir this what I have: > names(data)
[1] "Host"        "TimeStamp"   "TimeZone"    "Command"     "RequestLink" "HTTP"       
[7] "ReplyCode"   "Bytes"      
>

Comment: alsoI reposted the question with the input file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781639/stuck-at-creating-a-bell-curve-in-r-dont-know-to-determine-or-extract-height

Comment: also sir for my case, height <- c(1,1,2,3,1), what should the C part be? or do I even need it? Can I just do a simple as.numeric(height)?

Comment: hey sir just curious what should I set my height chart be? what would you set it be?